# How to get getSharedPreferences in android?

Tags: java, android

I have two activities(MainActivity and Player). In MainActivity I have created two methods:

```
private final long DEFAULTLONG = 0;
public long getTotalPlayTime(){
        SharedPreferences sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("TotalPlaybackTime", MODE_PRIVATE);
        long tempTotalTime = sp.getLong("totalPlayTime", DEFAULTLONG);
        return tempTotalTime;
}

public void updateTotalPlayTime(){
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("TotalPlaybackTime", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putLong("totalPlayTime", totalPlayTime);
        editor.commit();
 }
```

And when I am calling these two methods from Player activity, my app is crashing. 
I have instantiated the MainActivity in Player and called those methods by this line:

```
if (preferenceScheduler++ == 10) {
      f.updateTotalPlayTime();
      seconds2 = (f.getTotalPlayTime()) % 60;
      minutes2 = ((f.getTotalPlayTime() - seconds2)) / 60;
}
```

I don't know why, its gives me NullPointerException.

Here are the full error log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:161)
            at tushar.prime.primeplayer.MainActivity.updateTotalPlayTime(MainActivity.java:329)
            at tushar.prime.primeplayer.player.update(player.java:506)
            at tushar.prime.primeplayer.player.access$000(player.java:40)
            at tushar.prime.primeplayer.player$1.run(player.java:133)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post the code that calls `updateTotalPlayTime()` - you've probably instantiated an activity with `new` there (you shouldn't).

Comment: Yes you are right. I have instantiated the MainActivity in Player: `private static MainActivity f = new MainActivity();`

Comment: Maybe your calling updateTotalPlayTime before super.onCreate() method, call after super.onCreate(), Or else you can use application context.getSharedPreferences()

Comment: try to pass the application `context` as a parameter and then just create your `SharedPreferences` like this : context.getSharedPreferences("TotalPlaybackTime", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getSharedPreferences()` can only be called after `onCreate()` has been called on an `Activity`.

I would change your `updateTotalPlaytime()` method to

```
public void updateTotalPlayTime(Context ctx, String value){
        SharedPreferences sp = ctx.getSharedPreferences("TotalPlaybackTime", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putLong("totalPlayTime", value);
        editor.commit();
 }
```

And call it like this, in your `Activity` (after onCreate);

```
updateTotalPlaytimg(this, "value");
```

EDIT:

You should not instantiate your `MainActivity`. Instead, create the `updateTotalPlaytime();` method in your `PlayerActivity`.

Comment: Still having the problem. I have changed it to `f.updateTotalPlayTime(this);`

Comment: I have instantiated the MainActivity in Player: `private static MainActivity f = new MainActivity();`

Comment: Check my updated answer. You should not instantiate `MainActivity`. If you want to access the SharedPreferences, you could do so in `PlayerActivity`, as in my answer. @Tushar

Comment: Any time, happy coding. @Tushar

Answer (score 0):

I think people should use SharedPref with singleton because you can access every where you want for example i use it is like:

```
SharedPreferences preferences;
Editor editor;

public SharedPreference(Activity activity) {
    preferences = activity.getSharedPreferences(Const.XMLFILEPATH, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = preferences.edit();
}

public static SharedPreference getInstance(Activity activity){
    if(sharedPreference==null)
        sharedPreference = new SharedPreference(activity);
    return sharedPreference;
}
```

and when i want to edit or update sharedPref

```
public void isRootControlled(boolean isControlled){ 
    try {
        editor.putBoolean(Const.IS_ROT_CONTROLED, true); 
        editor.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {} 
}

public boolean isRootControlled(){
    return preferences.getBoolean(Const.IS_ROT_CONTROLED, false);
}
```